# Setting key problem: save and close just like vim

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-macros

I'm trying to use global-set-key to bind commands "`:x`" as save and close, just like the way vim do. Right now I'm doing:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-; x") (lambda() (kbd "C-x C-s") (kill-emacs)))
```

But when I type Shift+: and then x, it just write :x in the documents instead of really doing save and close. Wondering what should be the right form?

Comment: Make that `(kbd ": x")`. But that would only work if `":"` was a prefix key. Either pressing `:` inserts `:` or it waits for you to type the next character, it can't do both. Are you using a vi emulation interface? Which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function that does this already:

> (save-buffers-kill-emacs &optional ARG)
>
> Offer to save each buffer, then kill this Emacs process.
>   With prefix ARG, silently save all file-visiting buffers without asking.

You can call it interactively with `C-u M-x save-buffers-kill-emacs` and all files are saved without asking you and emacs quits, problem solved!

Your keybinding didn't work for two reasons:

1. `(kbd "S-;")` is not shifted ";" (i.e., ":"), it is ";" with the Super bit on. To bind to ":" just use ":" like this - `(kbd ":")`
2. ":" is not a prefix key, so you can't use it in a chain `(kbd ": x")` without further changes. Either you need to define a prefix-map  and bind it to ":" (see below), or investigate some other approach.

So, to get a save-all-and-quit bound to a key, the easiest solution is probably:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c x") 
    (lambda () 
        (interactive) 
        (save-buffers-kill-emacs t)))
```

Here the function is bound to `C-c x`, but you can change it to anything else.

If you really want to use ":" as a prefix, you'd do something like this:

```
(define-prefix-command 'my-keymap)
(global-set-key ":" my-keymap)

;; define kill-emacs:
(define-key my-keymap "x" (lambda () 
        (interactive) 
        (save-buffers-kill-emacs t)))
```

Now, of course, you've lost use of the : key for entering the ":" character. You can get it back by adding it to your keymap:

```el
(define-key my-keymap ":" 'self-insert-command)
```

Now entering `: x` will save all buffers and kill emacs, and `: :` will enter a ":".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Just add this to your `.emacs` and bind it to a key and you're done

```
(defun save-all-and-quit ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers t)
  (kill-emacs))
```

This is considering you want to save all buffers without prompting interactively for `yes` or `no` for all the unsaved buffers.

Comment: dunno why, it just write ":x" in the file when I type Shift+; and then x

Comment: do you know how to actually use it since I'm just writing :x in the file

Comment: Ah sorry, it looks like we can't use `shift` as a modifier key since it automatically inserts characters after it. Oh well. 
I guess you could use some other key binding for the function I wrote ? 
How about `super` key ?

Comment: it seems to be, ok

Comment: If you really want to use `shift-; x` to close emacs, I've no idea how to set it up to work that way. Maybe someone who knows more `elisp` can help you with that.